# Is there a way to push data into firebase without having the UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wish to create a reporting employee structure, I am using internal keys generated by the push function as EID's and will be nesting reporting employees EID under the reported employees EID. So for Eg. if a manager has a EID: -KbAGV6Uhg0BKK31HduN and a reporting engineer has a EID:                           -Kb9ioY8dkBEOO46uX7t the Json structure would look like

```
{
  "-KbAGV6Uhg0BKK31HduN " : {
      "reportingID" : "-Kb9ioY8dkBEOO46uX7t"
    }
  }
```

but because I am using the push function it looks something like this:

```
{
  "-KbAGV6Uhg0BKK31HduN" : {

    "-KbAH1RiVsz5FpSFudD2" : {
      "reportingID" : "-Kb9ioY8dkBEOO46uX7t"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't require this extra key(-KbAH1RiVsz5FpSFudD2)what can be done to avoid it or have something else like E1 or someother easy identifier in its place as the key is making the structure too complicated

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen please have a look

Comment: there is no need to ping me. I'll either have time to help or I won't, pinging doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen yes that's right, but you have answered most of the questions correctly hence I am pinging you also firebase documentation are very insufficeint

Comment: The push function itself isn't causing that. It's how your generated the reference the push function is using that is. Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is the Firebase way to handle things if you want to use push.

Instead of pushing, you could use the set method to do something like this:

ManagerID/directReports/EngineerID

where EngineerID could contain some additional info about the engineer or some key:value pair that would be useful to have in the app.

The JSON structure would look like this:

```
"ManagerGUID":{
    "directReports": {
        "EngineerGUID":{
            "someinfokey":"somevalue"
        }
    }
}
```

That way, if you want a list or iterable, you can just download the ManagerID/directReports node and have individual objects using the original key for the engineers. It might make some extra working in transforming to an array, but it sounds like this is kind of what you want to do. Let me know if I'm off base and I can update my answer.

Comment: I couldn't get what you are trying to say also I need a Json structure

Comment: @joel J_Everhart is right. Just use set function instead of push.
Everything you need is in Firebase documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: @joel I updated the answer to include the JSON structure. Hope that helps clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice but you can generate a global unique id for each entry instead of Firebase generated uid. 
Have a look a one of id generator here: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11